# iOS Development: What are some reasons I should to use XAuth to authenticate a twitter user?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, twitter, xauth

I see many people using XAuth in their app to authenticate twitter users and I'm wondering what are some situations that I would want to use XAuth in my own apps.

Thanks for your wisdom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have spent a lot of time hand crafting your UI, it can suddenly be very jarring to the user to have to goto a different UI to authenticate. For mobile in particular this can be jarring if the authentication page is not optimised for mobile as used to be the case with Twitter

Answer (score 3):

xAuth lets you skip showing a web view containing the Twitter login. It makes for a simpler and less jarring user experience for non-web apps.

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  Can't you use OAuth to login to twitter without using a web view?

Comment: I'm probably a bit late here, but no - you have to send the user to a Twitter web page to get a PIN.